# complex join/union query

Tags: mysql, join

Tables:

```
items -> id, userId, tagId, postedOn

itemsTags -> id, name

users -> id, firstName, lastName

usersFriends -> id, userId, friendUserId
```

The system needs a re-build, at the moment the flow is like this:

1. Get all the friends of the user.
2. Per friend (foreach) get the items the friend posted.
3. Get the tag data of the item (tagId).
4. Get the user data of the item (userId).

But the problem is, I need to sort it by date, and later on by a specific date for example, I want to see all the items of my friends that where posted today so I need a query that does those 4 queries in one, so basically `SELECT * FROM usersFriends JOIN items ON userId ...`

I just can't figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT F.*, I.*, IT.* 
FROM usersFriends UF 
  LEFT JOIN users F                  --- friends
    ON F.id = UF.friendUserId 
  LEFT JOIN items I                  --- items they posted
    ON I.userId = UF.friendUserId 
  LEFT JOIN itemsTags IT             --- tags of those items
    ON I.tagId = IT.id 
WHERE UF.userId = ??
```

Where on the questionmarks you place the user's id.

Comment: There was no result if the item had no tag how can I solve that problem?

Comment: First of all thanks for edit 'ypercube', way clearer now.. @Mike, for starters I guess you wanna select I.* instead of IT.* and if you have set the default value of your I.itemTag to null, then you should say something like.. ON i.tagId = IT.id OR i.tagId IS NULL

Comment: SELECT IT.*, U.* 
FROM usersFriends UF 
  JOIN items I 
    ON I.userId = UF.friendUserId 
  JOIN itemsTags IT 
    ON I.tagId = IT.id OR I.tagId IS NULL
  JOIN users U 
    ON U.id = I.userId 
WHERE UF.userId = '12663' isn't working ... am I not getting your answer, thanks for all the answers though!

Comment: You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`s to catch cases where friends have not any realted items and/or items have not any related tags.

Comment: Thanks guys for help! Left join fixed it, I'm shamed that I didn't know this!